# Python compare two json file and get only the difference

Tags: python, json, compare, diff

I want to compare two json file and get only the difference between them.

I have a code that can compare two json file, but he get me the line which is the same, and I want only the difference.

```
+     "AAAA": {
+       "name": "toto",
+       "age": null
+     },
      "BBBB": {
        "name": "tete",
        "age": 26
      },
-     "CCCC": {
?               ^ ^ ^^^
+     "DDDD": {
?               ^ ^ ^^^
-       "name": "tete",
?                   ^^^      ^
+       "age": "45",


with open('orig.json') as orig_file, open('target.json') as target_file:
    diff = difflib.Differ()
    result = diff.compare(target_file.readlines(),    orig_file.readlines())
    print("### JSON DIFF ###")
    print(''.join(result))
```

I don't want to keep if the key value is the same, but if the key value is differente, I want to keep the key.

FOr instance I don't want to keep "BBBB" key, beacause it is the same between two files, and other key I want to keep because, value is differente

Comment: If you load the json https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html you can compare them as dictionaries https://chrisalbon.com/python/basics/compare_two_dictionaries/

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ):

> Each line of a Differ delta begins with a two-letter code:

```
| Code | Meaning                                   |
|------|-------------------------------------------|
| '- ' | line unique to sequence 1                 |
| '+ ' | line unique to sequence 2                 |
| '  ' | line common to both sequences             |
| '? ' | line not present in either input sequence |
```

So basically, all you have to do is filter lines starting with either `"- "` or `"+ "`.

```
result = diff.compare(target_file.readlines(), orig_file.readlines())
result = [line for line in result if line.startswith(("- ", "+ "))]
```

Comment: yes, but I don't want to keep if the key value is the same, but if the key value is differente, I want to keep the key.

Comment: @locklockM You should update your question with this new information for other users to understand what you would like to achieve. Give an example with input files and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* apply julienc's answer - which is "technically correct" given your question's formulation - but doing a text diff on json strings is broken - there are many different valid json representations of the same data due to non-significant whitespaces / indentation and to the fact that json objects are defined as *unordered* collections (so `{"foo":42, "bar":true}` and `{"bar": true, "foo":42}` are textually different yet are strictly equals once unserialized.

IOW, the working solution is to deserialize your json data and do a proper dict comparison.

Comment: I guess text comparison could still be applied if you're using some kind of "prettifying" on your input, something like `json.dumps(..., sort_keys=True, indent=4)`. But I agree with you that unsererialized comparison is probably the best option. I just assumed from OP's question that their data was already formatted in a way that would work with text comparison.

Comment: @julienc didn't think of this actually. You should edit your answer to clarify those assumptions, really.